# When this code block runs, what happens logically step by step or how is the result evaluated?

Tags: node.js, loops, for-loop

I tried to run the following Node.js code:

```js
for (let a = 5; a === 11 ; a++) {
  console.log(a);
  }
```

I want to know how this loop returns the result . (Logically, step by step.) Why does it log nothing to the console?

*Example*:

- It starts with `5`.
- It then gets added by `1` each time.
- It's stopping condition is...

Thanks in advance and do ask in comments if the question wasn't clear.

Comment: This doesn't print anything. `5 != 11`, so the loop never iterates. The condition should be either `a < 11` or `a <= 11`.

Comment: This loop shouldn't work at all, the middle condition is a stop condition and since `a` is initialized to `5`, the stop condition will execute before we enter the loop...

Comment: Try: `for (let a = 5; a <= 11 ; a++) {
  console.log(a);
  }`

Comment: Ok now I got it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This particular loop should not print anything.

```js
for (let a = 5; a === 11 ; a++) {
  console.log(a);
  }
```

The loop states: "Execute the code inside me, as long as `a` is equal to `11`.
However, in our case, `a` is initialized to `5`. Because of this, when we first start the loop, its run condition is already false, so it never executes.

An example of a loop that would print the numbers from 5 to 10:

```js
for (let a = 5; a < 11 ; a++) {
  console.log(a);
}
```

It is important to note that the condition in a `for` loop is the run condition, not the end condition.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so your problem here is that it only runs if the variable A is equal to 11.
If you want everything from 5 below 11 you use a < symbol.

I'll explain the steps in this example.

```js
for (a = 5; a < 11; a++) {
    console.log(a)
}
```

1. It starts with 5.
2. It then gets added by 1 each time.
3. Its stopping condition is if A is greater than or equal to 11.